# How to initialize a Queue on a second core of an ESP32?

Tags: c, esp32, freertos, esp-idf

Currently I'm working on a Demo program to better understand working with FreeRTOS. Therefore I would like to try to initialize a Queue on my second core(core1). After initializing i would like to add something to it in a 1 second interval and whenever nothing happens I would like to check my queue and work its content off. Everything related to that queue should work on the second core. The reason being that I previously worked on a Webserver which operates on the main core. My future Queue is supposed to work in parallel on the second core.

This is my current demoprogram:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/semphr.h"
#include "freertos/timers.h"
#include "esp_system.h"

    xQueueHandle queue;



void taskqueuecreator()
{
 queue = xQueueCreate(15, sizeof(int));
 printf("Queue created on core %d!\n", xPortGetCoreID());

 vTaskDelete(NULL);

}

void addspitoqueue(){

    while(true){
        printf("added Item to Queue");
        xQueueSend(queue, 1, 1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}



void TimerStateMachine(int Methodnum){

    switch(Methodnum){
        case 1:
        printf("SPI communication with arm happens here %d \n",xPortGetCoreID());
        break;

        case 2:
        printf("something else is about to happen here");
        break;


        return;
    }



}

void queueloop(){
     int receivedint = 0; //1 = spi communication mit Arm
    while(true){
        printf("in queueloop");
        if(xQueueReceive(queue, &receivedint, 5000)){
        TimerStateMachine(receivedint);
        }
    }
}



void app_main(void)
{




xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(&taskqueuecreator, "create queue", 4*1024, NULL, 2, NULL, 1 );
printf("\n task done\n");
xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(&addspitoqueue, "create spitask", 4*1024, NULL, 2, NULL, 1);
printf("\n task done part 2\n");
xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(&queueloop, "queue loop", 4*1024, NULL, 2, NULL, 1);
printf("\n task done part 3\n");

}
```

when executing it I get the following errormessage followed by a reset :

> ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46
>
> rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT) configsip: 0,
> SPIWP:0xee
> clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
> mode:DIO, clock div:2 load:0x3fff0030,len:7028
> load:0x40078000,len:14308 load:0x40080400,len:3716 0x40080400: _init
> at ??:?
>
> entry 0x40080680 I (27) boot: ESP-IDF v4.3.1-dirty 2nd stage
> bootloader I (27) boot: compile time 10:17:24 I (27) boot: chip
> revision: 3 I (30) boot_comm: chip revision: 3, min. bootloader chip
> revision: 0 I (38) boot.esp32: SPI Speed      : 40MHz I (42)
> boot.esp32: SPI Mode       : DIO I (47) boot.esp32: SPI Flash Size :
> 8MB I (51) boot: Enabling RNG early entropy source... I (57) boot:
> Partition Table: I (60) boot: ## Label            Usage          Type
> ST Offset   Length I (68) boot:  0 nvs              WiFi data
> 01 02 00009000 00006000 I (75) boot:  1 phy_init         RF data
> 01 01 0000f000 00001000 I (82) boot:  2 factory          factory app
> 00 00 00010000 00100000 I (90) boot: End of partition table I (94)
> boot_comm: chip revision: 3, min. application chip revision: 0 I (101)
> esp_image: segment 0: paddr=00010020 vaddr=3f400020 size=06964h (
> 26980) map I (120) esp_image: segment 1: paddr=0001698c vaddr=3ffb0000
> size=028dch ( 10460) load I (124) esp_image: segment 2: paddr=00019270
> vaddr=40080000 size=06da8h ( 28072) load I (138) esp_image: segment 3:
> paddr=00020020 vaddr=400d0020 size=135bch ( 79292) map I (167)
> esp_image: segment 4: paddr=000335e4 vaddr=40086da8 size=03fb0h (
> 16304) load I (174) esp_image: segment 5: paddr=0003759c
> vaddr=50000000 size=00010h (    16) load I (180) boot: Loaded app from
> partition at offset 0x10000 I (180) boot: Disabling RNG early entropy
> source... I (196) cpu_start: Pro cpu up. I (196) cpu_start: Starting
> app cpu, entry point is 0x40080ffc 0x40080ffc: call_start_cpu1 at
> C:/Users/Student/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/port/cpu_start.c:141
>
> I (183) cpu_start: App cpu up. I (210) cpu_start: Pro cpu start user
> code I (210) cpu_start: cpu freq: 160000000 I (210) cpu_start:
> Application information: I (215) cpu_start: Project name:     main I
> (220) cpu_start: App version:      1 I (224) cpu_start: Compile time:
> Jan  3 2022 15:11:19 I (230) cpu_start: ELF file SHA256:
> 65b119d32e9f73f6... I (236) cpu_start: ESP-IDF:          v4.3.1-dirty
> I (242) heap_init: Initializing. RAM available for dynamic allocation:
> I (249) heap_init: At 3FFAE6E0 len 00001920 (6 KiB): DRAM I (255)
> heap_init: At 3FFB31A8 len 0002CE58 (179 KiB): DRAM I (261) heap_init:
> At 3FFE0440 len 00003AE0 (14 KiB): D/IRAM I (267) heap_init: At
> 3FFE4350 len 0001BCB0 (111 KiB): D/IRAM I (274) heap_init: At 4008AD58
> len 000152A8 (84 KiB): IRAM I (281) spi_flash: detected chip: generic
> I (285) spi_flash: flash io: dio I (290) cpu_start: Starting scheduler
> on PRO CPU. I (0) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on APP CPU.
>
> task done
>
> Queue created on core 1!
>
> task done part 2
>
> Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception
> was unhandled.
>
> Core  1 register dump: PC      : 0x4000c344  PS      : 0x00060633  A0
> : 0x80085685  A1      : 0x3ffb95e0   A2      : 0x3ffaffa8  A3      :
> 0x00000000  A4      : 0x00000004  A5      : 0x3ffaffa8 A6      :
> 0x00000001  A7      : 0x00000000  A8      : 0x40000000  A9      :
> 0x3ffb92a0   A10     : 0x3ffb92c0  A11     : 0x00000001  A12     :
> 0x3ffb9524  A13     : 0x3ffaef6c A14     : 0x00000000  A15     :
> 0x00000001  SAR     : 0x00000008  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c   EXCVADDR:
> 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x400014fd  LEND    : 0x4000150d  LCOUNT  :
> 0xffffffff
>
> Backtrace:0x4000c341:0x3ffb95e0 0x40085682:0x3ffb95f0
> 0x40085b0e:0x3ffb9610 0x400d40d0:0x3ffb9650 0x40087b39:0x3ffb9670
> 0x40085682: prvCopyDataToQueue at
> C:/Users/Student/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/queue.c:2114
>
> 0x40085b0e: xQueueGenericSend at
> C:/Users/Student/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/queue.c:804
>
> 0x400d40d0: addspitoqueue at
> C:\Users\Student\Projekte\sample_project\build/../main/main.c:30
> (discriminator 1)
>
> 0x40087b39: vPortTaskWrapper at
> C:/Users/Student/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/port/xtensa/port.c:168
>
> ELF file SHA256: 65b119d32e9f73f6
>
> Rebooting...

I assume(but I'm not 100% sure) this is caused by this line

> xQueueHandle queue;

Being executed on core 0 and this part

> ```
> while(true){
>     printf("added Item to Queue");
>     xQueueSend(queue, 1, 1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
>     vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
> }
> ```

Being executed on core 1.

If so, anyone might have an idea of how to work around that problem?
if not, anyone got an idea of what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to assume where the problem is; the answer is in the backtrace that you posted. The exception happened during a particular function call in your code:

```
0x400d40d0: addspitoqueue at C:\Users\Student\Projekte\sample_project\build/../main/main.c:30
```

Your function `addspitoqueue()` is:

```
void addspitoqueue(){

    while(true){
        printf("added Item to Queue");
        xQueueSend(queue, 1, 1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}
```

Specifically this line is causing the problem:

```
        xQueueSend(queue, 1, 1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
```

Take a look at the definition of [`xQueueSend()`](https://www.freertos.org/a00117.html):

```
 BaseType_t xQueueSend(
                            QueueHandle_t xQueue,
                            const void * pvItemToQueue,
                            TickType_t xTicksToWait
                         );
```

It's meant to take a pointer to the object to be placed on the queue - not the value. It will copy the object to the the queue starting at the address you passed - in this case, `1`, which is definitely going to cause a crash.

You need to store the value in an `int` (since you defined the queue to be a queue of `sizeof(int)` objects) and then pass a pointer to where you stored it.

For instance:

```
static int value_to_queue;

void addspitoqueue(){

    while(true){
        printf("added Item to Queue");
        value_to_queue = 1;
        xQueueSend(queue, &value_to_queue, 1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello romkey,

that did the trick! thanks!